# MS Access linking to Office 365 Sharepoint not working

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, office365

We have a access database split to front-end and back-end.  How to link the back-end to sharepoint so that everybody can access it with their front-end desktop client?

I have created Sharepoint lists by exporting the database to sharepoint.  I have also tried to import the lists into desktop access, but when I update the original tables, I do not see the changes reflected in the imported lists, or the lists on sharepoint.

What am I doing wrong, and is this the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a new access file you should select:
External Data -> More (Under Important & Link) -> SharePoint List

Then make sure you pick "Link to the data source by creating a linked table." Follow the steps in the wizard and the new tables should appear yellow or gold in your access objects viewer (left hand side of main access screen)

If your data is not updating in the linked tables, you may need to select Refresh (or Refresh All) on the Home tab to make sure you have the most current data.

Comment: Yes, I have done that.  The problem is not with the linked table (yellow/gold) table. If I open that and edit it, the changes are reflected in the sharepoint list on the web.  What I need is to update the original table (blue color) that are linked via the (Linked Table Manager) to my front-end database that contains all the forms.  Because my forms are linked to the back-end access tables (blue color) via the Linked Table Manager to these tables, if I update this table shouldn't it cascade the changes to the linked list (yellow/gold) table.

Comment: If your lists are showing up blue in Access they aren't configured to push or receive changes from anywhere. When you say your forms are contained in the original table, do you mean the form uses that table as a data source? Or that your forms are actually inside of this other table?

Comment: If you are familiar with the split database design, where there is a separate back-end access database, linked via linked table manager, to the front-end access database which contains the forms.  The back-end database which contains the tables, I created lists for on the sharepoint via sharepoint export.  This put them on sharepoint.  I also did a sharepoint import/link, which created them in access (golden) tables.  The blue (original) ones are still there, but now I have gold tables also.  My front-end is still linked via table manager to blue table

Comment: If I cannot use the original back-end tables via linked table manager, and require instead to link to golden tables, how to do this?  I tried link table manager, but it does not recognize those golden tables as valid.

Comment: Do I need somekind of macros setup in the blue table, so when it is updated, it cascades them to the golden tables so sharepoint is updated?

Comment: You'll need to link your front-end forms to the sharepoint-linked (gold) tables -- you'll need to change the "Record Source" for each of your forms. Luckily, if your tables have all the same field names it's really easy, you just open the form in designer view, open the properties pane, and select the little box at the top left of the form view (you want properties for the whole form), then change the "Record Source" value to your linked table as appropriate. If you have other linked relationships it will be more work unfortunately...